# How can i Get Better Time Result on This Mysql Query

Tags: mysql, join, time

i am Using This Mysql Query and is working Good, But i need go get a Better Time result. How can i do it?

```
SELECT TblExistencias.id as ID, TblExistencias.codigo as Codigo, 
       TblPartes.detalle as Detalle,TblPartes.neto1 as PrecioActual, 
       TblExistencias.Condicion_Producto as Condicion,TblCategorias.categoria as Categoria, 
       TblSubcategorias.subcategoria as Subcategoria, TblExistencias.costo as Costo, 
       TblExistencias.serial as Serial, TblExistencias.vendido as Vendido, 
       TblConceptosFacturas.ventaonline as VentaOnline, TblRemitos.nroremitocompleto as Remito, 
       TblFacturas.nrofacturacompleto as Factura, TblFacturas.fecha as FechaVenta,
       TblConceptosFacturas.ventaTotUn as Venta,TblConceptosFacturas.comisionmlunit as Comision,
       TblFacturas.costoenvio as Envio, if(TblExistencias.vendido =1, 
       TblConceptosFacturas.ventaTotUn - TblExistencias.Costo - TblConceptosFacturas.comisionmlunit - TblFacturas.costoenvio,0) as Ganancia, 
       TblProveedores.razonsocial as Proveedor, TblFacturasCompras.nrofacturacompleto as Compra, 
       TblFacturasCompras.fecha as FechaCompra, TblClientes.razonsocial as Cliente 
from TblExistencias 
    left join TblPartes on TblExistencias.codigo = TblPartes.codigo1 
    left join TblRemitos on TblExistencias.id_RemitoVenta = TblRemitos.id
    left join TblFacturasCompras on TblExistencias.id_factura = TblFacturasCompras.id 
    left join TblClientes on TblRemitos.id_cliente = TblClientes.id 
    left join TblFacturas on TblRemitos.id_factura = TblFacturas.id 
    left join TblConceptosFacturas on TblFacturas.id=TblConceptosFacturas.id_factura and TblConceptosFacturas.codigoproducto = TblExistencias.codigo 
    left join TblCategorias on TblCategorias.id = TblPartes.id_categoria 
    left join TblSubcategorias on TblPartes.id_subcategoria = TblSubcategorias.id 
    left join TblProveedores on TblFacturasCompras.id_proveedor = TblProveedores.id 
order by comision desc
```

Comment: Creatiung indexes on each relational columns (in all tables) like on `TblFacturasCompras.id_proveedor = TblProveedores.id`

Comment: what @Roy said is about the best you can do you seam to be wanting all table data from all tables ? With a good amount off data this will take some time not much that you can do about...

Comment: Thanks for response, All Tables, have Indexes in ID Columns.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is create an [index](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-indexes.htm) on **each relational columns**, like:

```
TblFacturasCompras.id_proveedor = TblProveedores.id
```

Answer (score -2):

Problem was in order clause, Query passed from 87 Secs to 4 Secs. Thanks for help.

Comment: What did you do - remove the order by?